# Stackoverflowexception error in my generic list code, c#

Tags: c#

I get the error: "Process is terminated due to StackOverFlowException" everytime I try to run my code. When I look at the warning I get it on my properies that says "make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion". Here is my code:

```
class Book
{
    public string bokensTittle
    {
        get { return bokensTittle; }
        set { bokensTittle = value; }
    }
    public string forfattareFornamn
    {
        get {return forfattareFornamn;}
        set {forfattareFornamn = value;}  // on this line i get the error
    }

    public string forfattareEfternamn
    {
        get {return forfattareEfternamn;}
        set {forfattareEfternamn = value;;} 
    }

    public int lanseringsDatum
    {
        get { return lanseringsDatum; }
        set { lanseringsDatum = value; }
    }

}
```

Could anybody help me to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You have a simple, endless recursion here.

Both of your properties are accessing themselves.

There are two ways of fixing it:

1. Automatic properties:

   ```
   public string ForfattareEfternamn
   {
       get; set;
   }

   public int LanseringsDatum
   {
       get; set;
   }
   ```
2. Backing fields:

   ```
   private string _forfattareEfternamn;
   private int _lanseringsDatum;

   public string ForfattareEfternamn
   {
       get { return _forfattareEfternamn; }
       set { _forfattareEfternamn = value; } 
   }

   public int LanseringsDatum
   {
       get { return _lanseringsDatum; }
       set { _lanseringsDatum = value; }
   }
   ```

BTW: Please note how I changed the names of the properties to start with an upper case letter. That's the accepted standard for public members in C#.

Answer (score 2):

The names of your properties matches the names you are using in the getters and setters. Declare only get;set; statements if you are not intending to use private variables.

```
class Book
{
    public string bokensTittle
    {
        get;set;
    }
    public string forfattareFornamn
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public string forfattareEfternamn
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public int lanseringsDatum
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling property from getter, which call property and so on.

```
public string forfattareEfternamn
{
    get {return forfattareEfternamn;} <-- here you call property getter again
    set {forfattareEfternamn = value;} 
}
```

If you want to use back storage, then **field and property should have different names** (usually camelCase name for back storage, and PascalCase name for property):

```
private string forfattareEfternamn; // field for storing property value

public string ForfattareEfternamn // property
{
    get {return forfattareEfternamn;} // returning field value
    set {forfattareEfternamn = value;}  // setting field value
}
```

But in your case you can simply use auto implemented property:

```
public string ForfattareEfternamn { get; set; }
```

I **strongly** recommend you to read [Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

Comment: so for example, instead of this:    public string forfattareFornamn
        {
            get {return forfattareFornamn;}
            set {forfattareFornamn = value;}
        }

Comment: i should write:    public string ForfattareFornamn
        {
            get {return forfattareFornamn;}
            set {forfattareFornamn = value;}
        }

Comment: @user2057693 simply write `public string ForfattareEfternamn { get; set; }` because you don't have any logic in your properties

Answer (score 1):

```
 public string forfattareEfternamn
    {
        get; 
        set;
    }

    public int lanseringsDatum
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

I believe autoproperties is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
public string forfattareEfternamn
{
    get;
    set;
}

public int lanseringsDatum
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of your get statements reference themselves. Any time you try to retrieve either property it will call its own get over and over. This is the infinite loop and the cause of the stack overflow.

Instead, you can use a backing field.

```
private string _forfattareEfternamn;

private int _lanseringsDatum;

public string ForfattareEfternamn
{
    get {return forfattareEfternamn;}
    set {forfattareEfternamn = value;;} 
}

public int LanseringsDatum
{
    get { return lanseringsDatum; }
    set { lanseringsDatum = value; }
}
```

Alternatively, if you need no additional code in the properties, blank get/set will be fine for you.

```
public string ForfattareEfternamn
{
    get;
    set;
}

public int LanseringsDatum
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

(Also in your setter for the first you have an extra ;)